# High power IR transmitter circuit for ESP8266

Tags: infrared, basic, esp8266

Currently I am using this IR transmitter circuit for an ESP8266:

[image]

It works, the reception is not bad, but I need a little bit higher power to control my AC unit. The AC unit is ca. 10 meter away from the transmitter. From about 5 meter it is working nicely.

Do you have any idea how to get more power through the diodes?

Comment: I've used single LEDs to communicate over 30m @100mA pulse , what LED beam-width or PN are you using?  Change R1 to 330 Ohms add series R to collector in Ohms to get 100mA

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using TSAL6100's: http://www.vishay.com/docs/81009/tsal6100.pdf . I'll try to change R1 to 330Ohms, but I didn't understand the second instruction. :) Do I need one more resistor before LEDs?

Comment: I think the 330Ohm did the trick, it works now from 10 meter. Do I need a 10ohm resistor before the LEDs?

Comment: If you have 1 Ohm or less add to measure current or any other means to know what If is and adjust accordingly

Comment: check answered if satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are rated probably much higher than yours.

### > **SFH 4550** 1.1W/sr @100mA +/-3 deg $0.70 approx.

Three should drop 4.5V typ 4.8V max allowing 0.2-0.5 Vce drop with base current of 10mA The 2N3904 is not a great choice. It will have Vbe=1.5V @Ib=10mA so consider a better NPN. Even PN2222 is marginal.

Using a PN2222 Vbe=1.3V max @Ib=15mA Rbe~40 Ohms above0.7V

- I calculated this way. Assuming driver Rout=50, Rbe=40 above 0.7V
- using (5-0.7)V/10mA= 430 Ohms then subtract {Rout+Rbe} Ohms allowance for CMOS driver and bulk VBE resistance giving Rb=430-90=340 Ohms
- with Vce(sat) for PN2222 =0.4max @150mA or PN2222A=0.3Vmax @150mA
- this gives some tolerance on Ic with variance on LED and Vce drops, so adding <=1 Ohm to emitter allows you to measure If.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: as long as nothing gets hot, you are good to go even further